# Why are Ion thrusters so energy hungry?

Tags: energy, charge, propulsion

Ion thrusters need a lot of energy. But I don't understand why. So, one thing I understand is that it takes a lot of energy to take achieve a high exhaust velocity ( since kinetic energy is proportional to velocity squared) but we get little momentum. This is all great. But, the energy required is coming from the grids. The charge present on these grids doesn't change (due to ion optics), hence they can accelerate particles forever as long as the ionization chamber has sufficient pressure to let the ions enter the grid space. Now, it takes energy to ionize the gas. But when I calculated it, its not in Kilowatts obviously. The chambers walls are positively charged. The walls act like an anode and take in the electrons from the plasma. So, the thing that I was wondering about was whether the constant charging of these walls could take up that much energy. I then tried to calculate the energy needed to do this through the knowledge of the metals work function and found out that it requires less than 100 watts of energy. I AM PRETTY SURE THIS IS WRONG, but I don't understand why ion thrusters are so energy hungry.

[image]

Comment: I'm sure it takes some power to maintain a 1315 V difference across that grid.

Comment: But if the grid is properly designed, then very few ions would hit it.So, the charge accumulation would be pretty low. So, just charge the grids before the voyage begins. Maintaining the potential difference wouldn't be a big problem. Is this how they do it?

Comment: I don't think the ions have to hit it.  I assume that grid is there to impart some sort of direction (and speed?) to the ions.  This wouldn't be for free, there would be expended energy in that process.

Comment: Yeah, the potential energy just gets converted into converted into kinetic energy and the charge doesnt change. Hence, we do not have to 'supply' energy directly. Maybe indirectly... like the charging of walls so the ions could enter the grid space in the first place?

Comment: The charge doesn't change because there is some form of power being supplied to the grid to maintain that voltage difference.  If the potential energy is converted to kinetic energy; there must be a power cost to supply that energy.

Comment: Now, if I stop supplying the potential.( Assuming the grids are already charged), and no charge particle leave or enter the grids, then how does the charge change??

Comment: If you stop sending particles through the grid, how are you getting any power out of it?

Comment: I meant what if the grids were already charged and then they are left undisturbed. Doesn't that violate the conservation of charge?

Comment: How does it violate the conservation of charge?  I'm not sure if those grids would hold onto their charge on their own anyways; but that's kind of a different issue altogether.

Comment: Why would they lose their charge?

Comment: Because there's a huge potential energy difference between those two plates.  Generally if there's a potential difference; nature tries to get energy from the potential and release that energy.  Since this is more of an active system, I doubt there is a method in place to maintain the difference in the plates when it isn't being used.

Comment: The minimum power requirement is (beam current)*(applied voltage) - it is just a circuit element. You can't just charge the plates and let them alone, unless there is no current (and hence no thrust). You have a conceptual problem on how ion beams work - ion current is current, and accelerating ions takes power - you have to supply both of those.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [crossposting](http://space.stackexchange.com/q/20017) is [frowned upon](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068/263383).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An idealized ion thruster might work like this:

First we make some gas that is neutral and non-conducting, conductive. That takes some energy. Then we charge the conductive gas positively, that takes some energy.

If there happens to be an electric field, maybe caused by some charged grids, in that place where the gas that we are charging is located, then the gas starts to feel a force after becoming charged.

As we are charging the gas, that takes energy. As we are not charging any grids, we are not using any energy to charge any grids.

How do we charge a conductive gas positively? We connect the positive terminal of a voltage source on it. When the voltage source is charging the gas, it is using energy.

Now we would like to know how much energy the charging takes. "Charging" means cramming a lot of similar charges in a small volume. We can charge some gas positively near a negative grid without using much energy, while near a positively charged grid charging some gas positively takes quite a lot energy.

It happens to be so that we want the positively charged gas to be near a positively charged grid, and far from a negatively charged grid, so that the positively charged gas will spend quite long time accelerating away from the positive grid and towards the negative grid. And that is why the voltage source that is charging the gas has to use quite a lot of energy.

Comment: Thank God! Now I finally understand why it takes a lot of energy for plasma separation. So, it because of the positive potential. Isn't it?

Comment: Yes. Potential is positive near the positive grid. Positive ions are leaving that place, which decreases the potential, and our power source is pulling electrons out of that place, which increases the potential. Potential is staying constant and preferably highly positive, as we are constantly positively charging that place, from which positive charges are constantly flying out, at high velocity if the potential is high.